# how to call Moo_CloudZoom block another template? Moo_CloudZoom extenstion use products list or grid page page

Tags: module, extensions

how to call Moo_CloudZoom block another template? Moo_CloudZoom extenstion use products list or grid page. i want add Moo_CloudZoom in my product list popup.

I just want to add moo_cloudZoom Extenstion use here. I want try to call it's block here.

I am using VS_Ajax Extenstestion for add to cart. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <block type="moo/product_view_media" name="media_list" as="media_list" template="moo/catalog/product/view/media.phtml">
 </block>
```

i Got It. it' can be use this code. You can call you yourock in xml file and after writwriting itsme
as `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media_list') ?>` I do this it can working.